Zero gas fee for transactions
I saw some people on ethereum and bsc chain that execute transactions paying 0 gwei per gas. How is it possible and how to do the same thing?

share the transaction.

tx of transaction zero gas fee 0xe4b4c98c97c14011c55c74607cf57355fb740759b1d174982070b596dabebbfe
